# How to make closure outer scope reference weak. Or any other workaround

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

**Assumption 1.** I have utility class called `Experiment`. It helps listening EnterFrame events on chosen sprites. The API looks following: `Experiment.listenEnterFrame(mySprite, onEnterFrameHandler);`.

**Assumption 2.** I want my `Experiment.listenEnterFrame` class to allow using anonymous handlers. I also want it to be memory-leak resistant (without any `cleanUp()` method), i.e. reference to mySprite should be weak.

Here's the code:

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.system.System;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

public class Experiment extends Sprite
{
    public function Experiment()
    {
        new MemoryLeakTest();
        new NoMemoryLeakTest();
        setTimeout(System.gc, 100);
    }

    private static var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);

    private static function listener(event:Event)
    {
        dict[event.currentTarget]();
    };

    public static function listenEnterFrame(dispatcher:Sprite, callback:Function):void
    {
        dict[dispatcher] = callback;
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, listener, false, 0, true);
    }
}
}

import flash.display.Sprite;

internal class MemoryLeakTest extends Sprite
{
    function MemoryLeakTest():void
    {
        Experiment.listenEnterFrame(this, function () {
            trace("Memory leak");
        });
    }
}

internal class NoMemoryLeakTest
{
    function NoMemoryLeakTest():void
    {
        Experiment.listenEnterFrame(new Sprite(), function () {
            trace("No Memory leak");
        });
    }
}
```

In above example, the MemoryLeakTest instance is never removed - tracing "Memory leak" forever.

My interpretation of that is that `callback` closure created in `MemoryLeakTest` keeps reference to outer scope, which is `MemoryLeakTest` instance itself. Because of this reference, `MemoryLeakTest` instance can't be garbage collected.

Do you know any workaround, so I can use anonymous callbacks in my utility method without having to worry about memory freeing?

Comment: It is highly unusual to create new instances of classes without storing those instances in a variable; as you do in the constructor.  I'm not sure if that is related to the memory issue or not, though.

Comment: I've most readable example I could. Instances can be easily stored in variables and nullified just before caling System.gc(). It doesn't matter.

Comment: You may want to use AS3Signals, since it already handles much of this. You may also want to consider that ENTER_FRAME is a broadcast event, which means that there's no advantage to listening to a particular instance for that event.

Comment: ENTER_FRAME is just for demonstration purposes, the real usage would be to use utility methods like this: `bind(dispatcher, property, changeHandler)`, e.g. `bind(this, "text", function() {trace("text changed")});`. How AS3 Signals can help in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There's a known bug with Dictionaries in AS3. Instead of storing references to functions/methods, references to the closure objects are stored instead.

Which means that if you would like to store a function reference as a *key* in a Dictionary it will immediately be marked for GC, if the Dictionary uses weak keys, since the Dictionary is referencing the closure object and not the function itself.

This also means that if you try to store a function reference as a *value* in a Dictionary then the instance the closure object refers to will not be GC'd as long as the Dictionary holds the closure object. (Dictionaries have weak *keys* not values !) 
Which is exactly what is happening here.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I supposed. But the question is, how to workaround this particular use case? So I can create utilities like `bind(dispatcher, property, onChangeListener)` used with anonymous functions without need to worry about `unbind(...)`.